Update Unity Leaderboard Metadata Without New Score
I’m using Unity’s built-in Leaderboards for my game. I want to be able to change the metadata attached to a player so they can change teams, but AddPlayerScoreAsync() only works if the player has a new high score.
I know I can change the player’s name with UpdatePlayerNameAsync(), but the metadata seems tied to the score rather than the name.
Is there some way to update the metadata without requiring a new score from the player?

https://docs.unity.com/ugs/manual/leaderboards/manual/add-new-score#Add_a_new_score_with_metadata does not say it has to be a new highscore, just that To add or update an entry for the player in the specified leaderboard. What is the result you are getting from the call?

Yeah, we realized we could update to latest score rather than highest. Thanks for your time

Never mind, I figured it out. On Unity Cloud's leaderboard setting it was just changing to Latest score and storing the highest locally.
Hopefully someone can find use from this

Just for the sake of clarity, what did you have to change the setting to? A screenshot may help.

Yeap, here it is https://imgur.com/a/KWSr0zT

Please edit this information into the body of your answer.
